# What's the difference between gtk_main_quit and gtk_widget_destroy when I want to destroy GtkWindows?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I  want to write three functions: main, B and C. All of them will construct an own GtkWindow and put some widgets in their own GtkWindow. the main function will call function B, and the function B will call function C. I want to the three functions will destroy their own GtkWindow from inside to outside when function is returned. All the functions will not disturb the left GtkWindows when destroying GtkWindow. So how should I do?

Comment: so every function can have a gtk_main()? and every gtk_main() responds to a gtk_main_quit()?

Comment: @noob you *can* nest `gtk_main()` but it's usually not needed, because you can have single main loop and multiple windows.

Comment: @ Alexander Dmitriev， So how to destroy current window without disturbing the left windows?

Comment: How about to show us a Code which can be checked? What exactly are you trying to achieve with your application?

Comment: @ Michi, this my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296540/why-does-the-subfunction-not-destroy-the-gtkwindow