# Why does the subfunction not destroy the GtkWindow?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome

This is my code:

```
 void window_first();
 void enter_window2(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data);
 void quit(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data);
 void quit();

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   GtkWidget* window2;
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   window_first();

   window2 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_widget_show_all(window2);

   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window2), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   gtk_main();
   return 0;
}
void quit(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data)
{
  exit(1);
}

void enter_window2(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

void window_first()
{
   GtkWidget* window1,  *vbox, *enter_window2_button;

   window1 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   enter_window2_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("enter_window2");

   vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 2);

   gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),enter_window2_button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window1), vbox);

   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window1), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(quit), NULL);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(enter_window2_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(enter_window2), NULL);

   gtk_widget_show_all(window1);

   gtk_main();
   return;
```

}

the purpose of my code is to construct a GtkWindow called "window1" which has a GtkButton called enter_window2 first and construct another GtkWindow called "window2" after the window1 was destroyed. I expect the window1 being destroyed by clicking the "enter_window2" button. However, when I run the code. things goes not as expected. In another word, when I press the button, the window2 is displayed, but the window1 is not destroyed. So how to solve it?

Comment: To me looks like you are trying to implement  something similar to the [GtkDialog](https://youtu.be/83KvC_o44Ik). Am I right?

Comment: That's not necessary though. And even if it seemed to be, running nested main loops (whether manually or with `gtk_dialog_run()`) is deprecated. GTK 4 doesn't even allow it AFAIK.

Comment: @Michi, Can I put GtkButton , GtkEntry and other GtkWidgets into GtkDialog?

Comment: Yes. It's just a window with some unfortunate functions added to run nested main loops for you, and some OK ones to get responses.

Comment: @ underscore_d, there should be only one main loop in my code?

Comment: @noob did you checked the link to those YouTube videos? There are enough informations to answer 99% all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need nested main loops for this, and you shouldn't use them anyway: they are an anti-pattern, and GTK is moving away from even allowing them (GTK 4 is removing `gtk_dialog_run()` and might not even let you 'roll your own').

You can and should simply use signals to do this. You just need to get them right. Chiefly: we must disconnect the `::destroy` handler on `window1` before we destroy it as part of switching to `window2`. Otherwise, it's easy:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void window_first();
void enter_window2(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data);
void window_second();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window_first();
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

void enter_window2(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWindow *window1 = GTK_WINDOW(data);
    g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func(window1, gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(window1));
    window_second();
}

void window_first()
{
    GtkWidget *window1 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *enter_window2_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("enter_window2");
    GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 2);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),enter_window2_button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window1), vbox);

    g_signal_connect(window1, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(enter_window2_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(enter_window2), window1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window1);
}

void window_second()
{
    GtkWidget *window2 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window2);

    g_signal_connect(window2, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
}
```

Note that you don't need to cast to `GOBject*` for `g_signal_connect()` or various other 'functions', which are really macros that check that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your great help! But I'm very confused about my code, Why does my code code fall flat?

Comment: You never told it to destroy the 1st window upon creating the 2nd one. For the rest, I'm not interested personally in analysing why your attempts to mess with 2 main loops failed, as that is not a pattern that should be encouraged. Nor is it at all needed here!

Comment: To destroy 1st window, I should use gtk_widget_destroy()?

Comment: Yes, that's how you destroy the window. That's what I did, and it's working, isn't it? As for `gtk_main()`, you should only run that once. That hands off control of your program to the GTK event loop, and you should perform all further responses to input through signals/callbacks that you connected before entering the main loop (or connect later in earlier callbacks, etc.). I don't really know how to say this better than [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk3-General.description) already does.

Comment: so,the window2 shouldn't be constructed in main function?

Comment: It should be constructed when it is needed. It is only needed once the button in `window1` is pressed and you want to open `window2` in response. So just do it in the callback for the `Button::clicked` handler, just as I did. My code does what you ask and is idiomatic. You should do things this way, with signals and callbacks, unless you have a very good, defined reason - rather than trying to bend GTK to your mistaken idea of how a GUI should work.

Comment: I want to build a login interface and a chat room. My original plan was to implement a subfunction to construct a login interface and main function to construct char room. So I should change my code as you did?

Comment: Of course I think you should do this, or I wouldn't have posted an answer suggesting to do this. You could also check how other similar programs handle such multi-window scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your help! can you introduce me some books about how to use gtk? I'm a beginer in using gtk.

Comment: I assume you have seen https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html . I seem to recall https://people.gnome.org/~swilmet/glib-gtk-dev-platform.pdf being good. Beyond that, I would just be searching, which you can do yourself ;-)

Comment: Can I replace g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_func() with g_signal_handlers_disconnect_by_data()?

Comment: In this case, no. How could you? Your `user_data` was `NULL` when you connected the signal. Just use whatever is suitable for the given situation. You could instead stash the result of `g_signal_connect()` somewhere and use that to disconnect only that one handler later. It's all about context. Doing what I did was the quickest way to fix your code. You can change it to whatever you want, so long as that works

Comment: What you called `gpointer data`. It's just a `void*` that can point to any other data required by your signal handler. Again, this will all be described in any half-decent GTK/GLib tutorial.